# JQUERY - Read Width & Height ob a flash object

Tags: jquery, flash

Is there any way to read the width and height of a flash object using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried something like $("object").height() and $("object").width(); are you using swfobject to embed the flash?

Comment: it worked! In the same way how can I set the width and height with jquery?

Comment: you could trying doing $("object").height(val); $("object").width(val);